# 2d openGl game in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I want to develop simple 2d opengl game with animation.in that animation I have to clip the image frame and draw it.
Any single  tutorial link or book which gives step by step Teachings to animate the image frame(sprite) and to do calculation.

Answer (score 1):

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430225997

Answer (score 0):

A free tutorial on OpenGL ES for the iPhone:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html